# Have commuting functions a common value ? 

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f,g: I \to I := [0,1]$ be continous functions satisfying $f \circ g = g \circ f$. Does 
there exist $x_0 \in I$ such that $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ ?

Background: In a homework the problem was posed with $g=\operatorname{id}$ (where 
it can easily be solved with the help of the intermediate value theorem). The 
lecturer said the stronger statement above is true, but he didn't know a proof. 
I googled a little around, but could only find something about the "commuting 
function problem" (existence of a common fixed point of $f$ and $g$) that is 
known to be false.

Comment: Yes. If not then $f(x) < g(x)$ (or the reverse inequality) by the intermediate value theorem. Then $f$ maps the minimum fixed point of $g$ to a smaller fixed point. Contradiction.

Comment: Btw, there was a question some time ago about the multidimensional generalisation of this. That is an open problem.

Comment: Here is the link http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3332/two-commuting-mappings-in-the-disk

Comment: Thank you all very much for the proof and the link and the quick reply. 

Comment: Well known; e.g. it's problem 518 (the last of the book) of Bernard Gelbaum's *Problems in Analysis*. 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. The set of fixed points of $g$ is closed, nonempty, and is mapped into itself by $f$. Letting $a\le b$ be, respectively, the minimum and maximum fixed points of $g$, we have $f(a)\ge a=g(a)$ and $f(b)\le b=g(b)$. So, by the intermediate value theorem, there is an $x\in[a,b]$ with $f(x)=g(x)$.

Also, to reiterate the points made in the comments, this is a difficult problem for more general domains. The case of commuting maps on the closed disc has been [asked before](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3332), and is still open. In fact, even the case of commuting maps on the simple triod (i.e., a capital 'T') appears to be an open problem, according to the contributed problem from Jeff Norden [here](http://notch.mathstat.muohio.edu/balogh_conference/booklet.ps) (*Commuting, coincidence-point-free maps on a triod*).

Comment: I see, I mixed two distinct problems: 
(a) common **value** is true for $n=1,$ unknown for $n \geq 2,$ (b) common **fixed point** is false for $n=1$ and we have nothing in print about $n \geq 2$, these all being on the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ so existence of fixed points for each map is automatic

Comment: @Will: (b) is false for $n\ge2$. Just take a counterexample for the $n=1$ case and extend to $I^n$ by making the maps fix the coordinates $x_i$ ($i=2,\ldots,n$).