# Do commuting homeomorphisms of the $2$-disk have a common fixed point?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Problem 2.20 (attributed to Lima) in [Kirby's list of unsolved problems in low-dimensional topology](http://math.berkeley.edu/~kirby/problems.ps.gz) asks:

> Are there commuting homeomorphisms of the $2$-ball $B^2$ without a
>   common fixed point?

What is the current status of this problem?

The answer is positive for higher-dimensional disks: Oliver (see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02565743#page-1), page 175) has shown that there is a smooth action of $\mathbb Z_{30}\times\mathbb Z_{30}$ without fixed points on some disk of sufficiently high dimension.

The question also seems vaguely related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3332/two-commuting-mappings-in-the-disk), about coincidence points of commuting self-maps of the disk. As stated there, such homeomorphisms are easily seen to have a coincidence point.